# "exclude" argument in `factor()` does not work

Tags: r

I'm confused about how this code should work:

```
foo <- factor(c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c"))
#[1] a b a c a a c c
#Levels: a b c

factor(foo, exclude = "a")
#[1] a b a c a a c c
#Levels: a b c
```

> Warning message:
>
> In as.vector(exclude, typeof(x)) : NAs introduced by coercion

Shouldn't it display factor with all `a` replaced by `NA`? If not, how to achieve this?

Comment: so basically it works when "x" argument is vector, but not when it is factor? if yes, is it possible to exclude value when "x" argument is factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed since R-3.4.0. The following answer now only serves as a historical reference.

---

As I said in my comment, at the moment `exclude` only works for

```
factor(as.character(foo), exclude = "a")
```

rather than

```
factor(foo, exclude = "a")
```

Note, the documentation `?factor` under R 3.3.1 is not satisfying at all:

```
exclude: a vector of values to be excluded when forming the set of
         levels.  This should be of the same type as ‘x’, and will be
         coerced if necessary.
```

The following are not giving any warning or error, but are also not doing anything:

```
## foo is a factor with `typeof` being "integer"
factor(foo, exclude = 1L)
factor(foo, exclude = factor("a", levels = levels(foo)))
#[1] a b a c a a c c
#Levels: a b c
```

Actually, the documentation appears quite contradictory, as it also reads:

```
The encoding of the vector happens as follows.  First all the
values in ‘exclude’ are removed from ‘levels’.
```

so it looks like the developer really expects `exclude` to be a "character".

---

This is more likely to be a bug inside `factor`. The problem is rather evident, that following line inside `factor(x, ...)` is making a mess when input vector `x` is of "factor" class:

```
exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
```

as in that case `typeof(x)` is "integer". If `exclude` is a string, `NA` will be produced when trying to convert a string to an integer.

I really have no idea why there is such a line inside `factor`. The subsequent two lines are just doing the right thing, if this line does not exist:

```
    x <- as.character(x)
    levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]
```

So, a remedy / fix is simply eliminating this line:

```
my_factor <- function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
                       ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA) 
{
    if (is.null(x)) 
        x <- character()
    nx <- names(x)
    if (missing(levels)) {
        y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
        ind <- sort.list(y)
        y <- as.character(y)
        levels <- unique(y[ind])
    }
    force(ordered)
    #exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
    x <- as.character(x)
    levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]
    f <- match(x, levels)
    if (!is.null(nx)) 
        names(f) <- nx
    nl <- length(labels)
    nL <- length(levels)
    if (!any(nl == c(1L, nL))) 
        stop(gettextf("invalid 'labels'; length %d should be 1 or %d", 
            nl, nL), domain = NA)
    levels(f) <- if (nl == nL) 
        as.character(labels)
    else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))
    class(f) <- c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
    f
}
```

Let's have a test now:

```
my_factor(foo, exclude = "a")
#[1] <NA> b    <NA> c    <NA> <NA> c    c   
#Levels: b c

my_factor(as.character(foo), exclude = "a")
#[1] <NA> b    <NA> c    <NA> <NA> c    c   
#Levels: b c
```